# How can I remove quotes in rss

Tags: html, drupal, rss, quotes

I have this in my RSS feed, in drupal views:

```
<link>Prueba &quot;con comillas&quot;</link>
```

I've tried to create a module like this:

```
function views_without_encoded_preprocess_views_view_views_rss(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['rss_feed'])) {
    $vars['rss_feed'] = strtr($vars['rss_feed'], array(
      '&amp;#039;' => '&#039;',
      '&amp;quot;' => '&quot;',
      '&amp;lt;' => '&lt;',
      '&amp;gt;' => '&gt;',
      '&amp;amp;' => '&amp;',
      '&quot;gt' => '',
    ));
  }
}
```

but everything is not ok. I continue seeing this part:

```
<link>Prueba &quot;con comillas&quot;</link>
```

Only for quotes.

Answer (score 3):

As I see you try to use the Views RSS.

There is a fix that appears to work but it has been tested only at Drupal 6 sites. In Drupal 7 some things changed but try out this one:

Go to **views_rss/theme** and open the **theme.inc**

Copy out the entire 'function template_preprocess_views_view_views_rss function, and put it in your theme's template.php.

Change the function name to: function **yourthemename**_precrocess_views_view_views_rss

Then at line 200 in the original theme, or where it reads '// Add XML element(s) to the item array' insert the following just above:

```
if (empty($rss_elements)) continue;
       // Insert here -- clean up special characters
       $rss_elements[0]['value'] = htmlspecialchars_decode(trim(strip_tags(decode_entities( $rss_elements[0]['value'])),"\n\t\r\v\0\x0B\xC2\xA0 "));
       $rss_elements[0]['value'] = htmlspecialchars($rss_elements[0]['value'], ENT_COMPAT);
       // end of cleaning
       // Add XML element(s) to the item array.
       $rss_item['value'] = array_merge($rss_item['value'], $rss_elements);
}
```

Check your RSS.... you might have to flush the cache a few times.

Another thing you could try is [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars). It seems to me that the output of the Views RSS fields could use this to force encoding on quotes, apostrophes, and ampersands.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user3718166: [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [this FAQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Bam.